# What ways there are to stop and restart JSCover Server and apply configuration changes?

Tags: command-line, configuration, scripting, jscoverage

At the moment to stop JSCover server I go to `http://localhost:8080/stop`.
What are other ways (commandline or not) to stop/restart JSCover server, in case one needs to apply some configuration changes and wants to do it in automated manner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None really, except if you run JSCover as a thread in a Java application (such as shown [here](https://github.com/tntim96/JSCover-samples/blob/master/src/test/java/jscover/webdriver/proxy/WebDriverUnderscoreProxyTest.java)).

You could put in a feature request at https://github.com/tntim96/JSCover/issues if you can describe exactly what you need and think it would be useful to others.